# How to skip interstitial in a django view if a user hits the back button?

Tags: python, django, caching, header, interstitial

I have an application with an interstitial page to hold the user while an intensive operation runs in the background (takes anywhere from 30 secs to 1 minute). Once the operation is done, the user is redirected to the results page.

Once on the result page, typical user behavior is to hit the 'back' button to perform the operation on a different input set. However, the back button takes them to the interstitial, not the original form. The desired behavior is to go back to the original form, skipping the interstitial entirely. I'd like this to be default behavior if the user goes to the interstitial page from anywhere but the original form.

I thought I could create this by using the `@never_cache` function decorator in my view for the interstitial, and logic based on `request.META['HTTP_REFERER']`, however the page doesn't respect these. The browser's back button still trumps this behavior.

Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Comment: What if you added a button to the results page to go back to the form?  Or wouldn't that overcome the users' urge to use the 'back' button?

Comment: It probably wouldn't curb the issue, but I like the idea. :) Unfortunately it doesn't address the main issue of how to get django to pay attention to caching and the back button & how to program logic for this.

Comment: Preventing a page from being cached doesn't mean that it isn't there. The back button goes into the history and gets the URL that is before the current page... and in your case, it is the interstitial. 

So, what  you are doing is preventing the browser from caching the page and so, when a user press the back button, it is downloaded again instead of being pulled from the cache.

Answer (score 2):

How do you keep the interstitial page from entering the flow? Eliminate it.

I'm only recently wrapping my head around AJAX, so wish I could give you a more concrete answer, but the general approach is to use something like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to replace the contents of the form `<div>` after submission with a "hey, I'm working here" indication and then a load of the new page when ready.

jQuery very kindly appends a unique, junk parameter to certain requests to explicitly thwart caching of volatile pages.